# Jsoup Complete text not getting parsed

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to parse a website that contains a large amount of data. When I print the parsed data, only a few characters get printed.How can I parse the entire text? My program is as follows:

```
String getText(String url){
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36")
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error in extracting text");
    }

    System.out.print(doc.body().text());
    return (doc.body().text());

}
```

The same code works perfectly on a MAC. I am using a Windows 10. My Jsoup version in 1.9.2. JVM on both windows and MAC is 1.8. On both windows and MAC the IDE used was eclipse. The content of the url is something similar to this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<h1>This is a test page</h1>
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you please add to your post your Jsoup version, JVM version (MAC and windows 10)? Can you also add the url or if not possible a sample of the content delivered by `url`? How do you run the program : command line or IDE? Which IDE (MAC and windows)?

Comment: @Stephan Hi I have updated with the info you requested.